# How to Add Reference via Developer Command Prompt

Tags: c#, console-application, windows

i was create  a C# program in notepad and save as "Program.cs"
 i need compile my program in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013

but i need add Reference some dll file 
 how to add Reference  to my program in in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Reference this: [Working with the C# 2.0 Command Line Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(v=vs.80).aspx) and
>   [How to: Create and Use Assemblies Using the Command Line (C# and
>   Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z.aspx)

If your client application is making use of MyCodeLibrary.dll, you need to make use of the `/reference (or simply /r) option`. This flag is flexible in that you may specify the full path to the *dll in question as so:

```
csc /t:exe /r:C:\MyCSharpCode\MyCodeLibrary\MyCodeLibrary.dll *.cs
```

Or, if a copy of the private assembly is in the same folder as the input files, you can simply specify the assembly name:

```
csc /t:exe /r:MyCodeLibrary.dll *.cs
```

Comment: hi @Niranjan Kala i need add two dll file, how  i add 2  Reference in a single cmd line?

Comment: repeat /r:anotherLibpath after giving one space.. e.g. `csc /t:exe /r:MyCodeLibrary.dll /r:NewLib.dll *.cs` or `csc /t:exe /r:MyCodeLibrary.dl;NewLib.dll *.cs`

Comment: For some reason `/r` [do not include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813904) `PresentationCore.dll`

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `/r` switch to add the dll reference like

```
csc /target:library /r:Assembly_Name.dll Program.cs
```